# codeigniter include css or js file

Tags: codeigniter

Why I can't include anything from views if it is inside application folder?

It is fine when I include in main dir:

This works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{ci_base_url}css/site.css" />
```

but this does not work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{ci_base_url}application/css/site.css" />
```

Why??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Only the content in what you called the "main dir" is directly accessible via http requests. That's for security reasons. Often that dir is named "public"

Comment: so how to include css file in app folder? I would like to keep my css for each layout like: views/default/css

Comment: I find it easier to have all my jquery, images, css and other items stored up in public, and some up above the root for security.  But I never really knew the reason you couldnt access them in the views.  Thanks Riccardo